# How to import odoo module from code in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, github, odoo

I cloned a github module (odoo-rtl) into a repo, then moved the directory under my odoo/addons dir. (And with Github-Desktop I located it again). I then refreshed my Eclipse ODOO project and I see the module under the addons directory.

I re-run odoo and then Activate the Developer mode. In the applications I do "Update modules" and then look for the module in the modules list. It is not there. What am I doing wrong and what should I do so that I see and can install the module from the module list?

Comment: May be there is access right issue on the module folder. try to change the access right of the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to check if odoo is not showing your module in the modules list. First would be to check if the folder contains the correct files (**init**.py , **manifest**.py (for V10 and **openerp**.py for V9) , models, views, etc. Maybe that the module is in a subfolder, in this case the module will not be read by odoo. Also please note that if you are using odoo v9 and you place a module for v10 which has **manifest**.py instead of **openerp**.py, the module will not be shown and read at all. The other thing to check is the permissions. If you are using linux the command to change the permissions would be:

```
$ cd /odoo/odoo-server 
$ sudo chmod 735 -R addons
```

After these checks the module should be shown in your apps list.
Cheers,
Riste Kabranov
Python/Odoo developer @ Nebiz IT DOOEL Skopje, Macedonia

Comment: It was the permissions. Thanks!!